# UINavigationController with custom UIBarButtonItem back button skips animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm having a really weird problem. I've hidden the back button displayed in a UINavigationController and inserted a custom left button to do the same job. It compiles and works 95% of the time. But it randomly skips the animation when popping af view, never when pushing. I can sit and repeat pushing and popping views and it's slides perfectly back and forth, but then occationally it just "jumps" to the view instead of animating. Any ideas why it does this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it was in the middle of animating and you pressed it again?

Comment: Have you checked if the same happens with the native back button?(Don't blame yourself yet :P).

Comment: Check if there any memory warning or leaking there. That may cause the animation fails.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers... I made a function to intercept the click before calling the pop-function to post a log message in the attempt of verifying a double-click. Strangely enough it completely resolved the problem. And I might know why... If I call a function which needs an object without one, will it then use what's randomly in the memory? Because when I added the pop-function, I didn't include a boolean for the "animating" parameter as it was added by addTarget.